# quadcopter motor spinning with resistance and not as freely as other motors

Tags: brushless-motors, motor

I haven't completed the assembly of my quad but I noticed one of the motors was not spinning as freely as the other 3. It seems like the top spinning part is scraping against the bottom fixed plate and making a quiet scratchy noise. I haven't used the motors that much yet and I noticed this from just spinning the motor from my fingers.

Comment: Have you had any crashes or been flying in a dusty/muddy environment?

Comment: nope. haven't flew it besides just running the motor off the radio transmitter and reciever and my area doesn't get very dusty

Comment: okay - and did it do this before you soldered it to the ESC?

Comment: the motors came in a kit with the ESCs with bullet connectors so there was no soldering needed

Comment: if you unplug the bullet connectors, does it still feel stuck? And did it do the same before you plugged them in?

Comment: Plugging the connectors in and out doesn't affect it. as far as i can remember, the motor was never like this until one day ago.

Comment: okay, thank you for checking that. The reason I needed to know is because if the motor is shorted, it gives extra resistance to turning. Assuming you have done a visual inspection and have checked the mounting bolts screws aren’t touching the windings, my next step would be to disassemble the motor and check everything look also alright internally. Only do this if you are confident you know what you’re doing, though

Comment: thank you, will do asap!

Answer (score 1):

If the quad already had some flight time, I would guess it was a burned esc, but in your case maybe your screws are too long or there is something stuck inside the motor.

Comment: how can the ESC be burned? during high current bursts when flying the drone? but i did take the screws off and same behaviour with the motor. i'll take the motor apart to look inside

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason or what happened to me when I had that issue was I got grass stuck on my motor when taking off.

Comment: hmm okay. well i can't take apart the motor because i don't have that skinny of a screwdriver.  i'll see what i can do